# how to find correlation between different dimension matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab, correlation, pearson

I have 2 matrices of dim 15*3 and 10*3 . I want to find their correlation (Pearson coefficient) between the 2 matrices. I used the command

```
result=corr2(A,B)
```

But i got the error stating that `A` and `B` of same size.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in that command. Is there any other way to find correlation between 2 different dimension matrices?

Comment: Correlation between two sets of data will require them to be the same size by definition - since you're trying to see how similar their (pairs of) entries behave. Maybe tell us what your ultimate goal is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `r = corr2(A,B)` ([documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/corr2.html)):

- it returns the correlation coefficient r between A and B, where A and B are matrices or vectors of the same size. r is a scalar double.
- If you still want to use `corr2`, you can do like:

  ```
  result = corr2(A(1:10, :), B)
  ```

---

**Solve**: for matrices of different dimensions, you should use `xcorr2`:

`C = xcorr2(A, B)`

[documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr2.html):

- C = xcorr2(A,B) returns the cross-correlation of matrices A and B with no scaling. xcorr2 is the two-dimensional version of xcorr.